# C++ sort long deque

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I'm trying to sort first half of a deque `deque<data> sortDValues` of pairs

```
struct data {
    int dValue;
    int index;
};
```

by the `dValue` using c++ function with lambda expression

```
sort(sortDValues.begin(), sortDValues.begin() + partASize - i,
     [](data const &a, data const &b) { return a.dValue > b.dValue; });
```

This approach works well most of time, but in some special cases the final program falls. I've located, that the problem of this is in the `sort` function, however, I couldn't figure out, why.

I'm not sure, if it can have anything in common with filling this `dequeue`

```
deque<data> sortDValues;
    for(number n : indices)
    {
        if(perm[n] >= partASize)
            sortDValues.push_back(dValues[n]);
        else
            sortDValues.push_front(dValues[n]);
    }
```

I can give a specific case of this problem: first number is the `index`, the second the `dValue`:

[image: Specific case]
Thank you in advance for answers, I wasn't able to find out, where the problem is.

Comment: did you make sure `sortDValues.begin() + partASize - i` is between `begin()` and `end()`?

Comment: @bolov yes, i'm sure, that this requirement is met

Comment: @E.Brown There is nothing wrong with `std::sort`.  The only thing that can be wrong is either 1) your iterators you're providing are invalid, 2) the sorting criteria does not adhere to a `strict-weak-order`, or 3) the data you've filled the container with has `data` with uninitialized / indeterminate values.  You never showed us 1) (even though you claim it is valid), and you haven't proven item 3).

Comment: @E.Brown Also, claiming that your iterator in `std::sort` is valid is not enough.  Ensure it's valid:  `size_t lastElement = std::min(sortDValues.size(), partASize - i); std::sort(sortDValues.begin(), sortDValues.begin() + lastElement, ...)`  Something similar to that ensures that you are not going out of bounds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried tu ensure, wheather these condition are met. To 1) with  `if (lastElement < 1) cout << "error"` and to 3) with `for(data d : sortDValues) cout << d.index << " " << d.dValue<< endl;` 
I haven't found any problem with this approach. I hope, that this proves, that conditions 1) and 3) are ensured.

Comment: Why do you need to check if `lastElement` is < 1?  If there are no items, the call to `sort` effectively becomes a no-op.  I think you need to provide an [mcve] instead of posting bits of code.  We have no idea where, when this code is called and in what context the code is called in.  Also, I looked at the picture you posted, and nothing there shows an error.  Numbers are decreasing at a certain point, then stops.  That stopping point could be that iterator your sort is stopping on.  So right now, I don't see what he problem is.